# Transformation of vectors to make them unit vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, linear-transformations

If I have $2$ vectors in the plane, how can I find the matrix transformation that when applied to each vector, makes them unit vectors? I am looking for the $2 \times 2$ matrix **A** that satisfies

$ \mathbf{A}v_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix} \ \ \ and \ \ \ \mathbf{A}v_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
1
\end{bmatrix} $

Where $ v_1 $ and $ v_2 $ are the column vectors.

The specific problem I need to solve is to find the single transformation that maps $ \begin{bmatrix}
120\\ 
60
\end{bmatrix} $ to $ \begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix} $ and $ \begin{bmatrix}
90\\ 
30
\end{bmatrix} $ to $ \begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
1
\end{bmatrix} $ however an answer that helps me with the general solution would be appreciated too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $A$ is simply the inverse of $$\begin{bmatrix}
120&90\\ 
60&30
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thanks very much, I had no idea it would be that simple.

Comment: @Nick_2440 You are welcome! If you write the problem in the form $AB=I$ it is immediate to see that. Bye